# How do you add a specific-to-device variable in HTML/CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, local

I am writing a website that keeps track of the election and I am adding an auto-refresh feature that refreshes every minute. Every time a variable (called `seconds`)  and my code is as follows:

```
var secInterval = 0

var secInterval = setInterval(function() {

  var secInterval = secInterval + 1

  if (secInterval == 60){
    location.reload();
    var secInterval = 0
  }

}, 1000);
```

I would like to let the user set the rate at which the page refreshes. Also, I need to know how to automatically trigger this script when the webpage is pulled up.

Comment: Google "javascript onload", "javascript forms", "dynamic html" (you don't need to reload the page, just update its content), and "mdn local storage". Stackoverflow isn't a code writing service, each question here is supposed to focus on a single, narrow topic, and the questions you're asking imply you should at least skim one of the longer javascript tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dropdown or any suitable input field to get the refresh interval input from the user. Then store that input in Local Storage. Then, when a user refreshes the page or visits the page again, it will use the saved refresh interval.

```js
if (localStorage.getItem("refreshTime")){
  var refreshTime = localStorage.getItem("refreshTime");
}else{
  var refreshTime = 60;
}

var secInterval = 0;
    
    setInterval(function() {
      console.log(secInterval);
    
      secInterval = secInterval + 1

      if (secInterval == refreshTime){
        location.reload();
        secInterval = 0
      }

  }, 1000);


function setRefreshTime(){
  var refreshTimeInput = document.getElementById("refreshTime");
  refreshTime = refreshTimeInput.value;
  localStorage.setItem("refreshTime", refreshTime);
  console.log(refreshTime);
  secInterval = 0;
}
```

```html
<select name="refreshTime" id="refreshTime">
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
  <option value="30">30</option>
  <option value="45">45</option>
  <option value="60">60</option>
</select>

<input type="button" value="Set Refresh Time"  onclick="setRefreshTime()"/>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This really helped! Do you mind if I credit you in the Credits section of the site?

Comment: Sure. Go ahead :)